# Eclipse showing target not found for Android SDK

Tags: android, eclipse

I have downloaded all the latest version but when i am adding android SDK location in my Eclipse preferences i am getting the following Error:
No target available

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone into the project properties and specified which API you are using for the project?